# Declarar variable de salida. Procedimiento almacenado MySql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `capturar_consecutivo`(numero int) RETURNS int
BEGIN
    DECLARE num int DEFAULT 0;
    SET num = ( SELECT * FROM consecutivo where consecutivo.numero=numero );
    RETURN num
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Estoy intentando crear este procedimiento almacenado con valores de retorno, pero al momento de crearlo el sistema me arroja un error:

> "#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'int BEGIN"

Pero no entiendo cual es el error, según yo la sintaxis esta correcta, ¿Alguien que me oriente en la sintaxis correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres regresar un valor tienes que utilizar una función y no un procedimiento almacenado

Para crear la función tendría que se por ejemplo de esta forma :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `capturar_consecutivo`(numero   INT) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE num INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET num = ( SELECT * FROM consecutivo where consecutivo.numero=numero );
    RETURN num;
END
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Pero también toma en cuenta que la parte:

`SET num = ( SELECT * FROM consecutivo where consecutivo.numero=numero );`

Asegúrate de que solo regrese un solo campo y un solo registro, sino tendrás un error.

Answer (score 1):

`RETURN` se utiliza para las funciones, no para los Store Procedure.

Elimina el `RETURNS int` y el `RETURN` al final y listo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `capturar_consecutivo`(IN numero int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE num int DEFAULT 0;
    SET num = ( SELECT * FROM consecutivo where consecutivo.numero=numero );
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```